# yii2 passing value from view to controller

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I have this kind of problem. I have an input text that have template of radio in it.

the problem is that I want to get the value of that radio when I check it and store it to the database field.

my idea is to create a variable from model but i can't pass the radio value to that variable when i save it.

please help me I am stuck with it.

here is the images of view:

[image: Generated view]

Controller action:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new QbQuestion();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $answer = $model->answer;
            $model->$answer;
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(Url::to(['qb-question/index']));
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="qb-question-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'label' => 'col-sm-4',
            'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-4',
            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-8',
            'button' => 'col-sm-8',
            'error' => '',
            'hint' => '',
        ],
    ],
]); ?>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_cat')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(QbCategory::find()->all(), 'id', 'category'),
            [
            'prompt' => 'Select Category'
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_date')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(QbDate::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id',
                function($model, $defaultValue) {
                return $model['month'].' '.$model['year'];
            }),
            [
            'prompt' => 'Select Date'
    ]) ?>

    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'question')->textarea(['rows' => 5]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_c1', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
            Html::radio('answer').'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_c2', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
            Html::radio('answer').'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_c3', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
            Html::radio('answer').'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_c4', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
            Html::radio('answer').'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>

        <?php echo Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>


    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post your code, not just an image of it? And the image would be better inserted into the question! It will make things more readable! Thnks

Comment: sorry im new to this site.my code is the same on that image. i tried to create from controller to save it but it didn't work. my controller code look like this:

public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new QbQuestion();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $answer = $model->answer;
            $model->$answer;
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(Url::to(['qb-question/index']));
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

Comment: Great! Now you just need to copy and paste the code you have in the image, the bit that starts with `$form->field`.

Comment: i hope i did it right to show you what you need to solve my problem. thanks :)

Comment: Do you intend that only one radio button should be selected, or can more than one be selected? And what values do your fields `q_c1`, `q_c2` etc hold?

Comment: yes only one radio can be selected. and that selected radio will be an answer. my fields are q_c1, q_c2, q_c3, q_c4, and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

radio field that you have take will always return 1, So you can't identify selected answer. You can do it normal html as below:

Change in Your Form file :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'q_c1', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
        '<input type="radio" name="QbQuestion[answer]" value="q_c1">'.'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_c2', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
            '<input type="radio" name="QbQuestion[answer]" value="q_c2">'.'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_c3', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
            '<input type="radio" name="QbQuestion[answer]" value="q_c3">'.'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'q_c4', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
            '<input type="radio" name="QbQuestion[answer]" value="q_c4">'.'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>
```

Here ,`QbQuestion['answer']` return you the selected answer.

Change in controller:

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new QbQuestion();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

          // if you have answer attribute in model class than load that attribute
          // no need of this line $answer = $model->answer;
          // no need of this line  $model->$answer;

          // you can do it manually as below
           $model->answer=$_REQEST['QbQuestion']['answer'];

            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(Url::to(['qb-question/index']));
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are a life saver sir :) that's what i want ^_^.

thank you very much

Comment: sir can you help me get out this problem too:

[click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927919/yii2-get-name-instead-of-id)

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your attributes are not saving is because you haven't tied the field to the model, so incorrect field names are being submitted in the form.

It seems to me as if what you need is a `radioList`. The `Html::radio()` method just adds a radio button, not tied to any model. To use a `radioList` you need to do something like this;

First, create an array of possible answers in your view file;

```
$answers = array('q_c1' => $model->q_c1, 'q_c2' => $model=>q_c2, 'q_c3' => $model=>q_c3, 'q_c4' => $model=>q_c4);
```

Now, because it's a radio list, it will only submit data for one of the radio button. It will not allow selection of more than one radio button. Because of the way you are storing your data, you will need a temporary model attribute to store this value oin while the model gets populated and validated. Create this in your model like so;

```
public $answerToQuestion;
```

And allow it to be massively assigned;

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['answerToQuestion'], 'safe]
    ];
}
```

Now you can create your form field like this;

echo $form->field($model, 'answerToQuestion')->radioList($answers);

Yii should now generate the list of radio buttons with the correct names to tie them into your model and allow them to be massively assigned.

The attributes submitted by the form will be of the form (assuming your model is called `Question`;

```
Question[answerToQuestion] => 'q_c2'
```

It will pass validation. It's now up to your model logic to decode the selected answer into the relevant fields in your database.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i get your point. but as my design i need to do like the image of view that i posted. can you help me to make another solution to tied my radio to my model using this line:

 <?= $form->field($model, 'q_c1', [
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">'.
            Html::radio('answer').'</span>{input}</div>',
    ]); ?>

thank you.

Comment: even just to identify if i checked any of the button. for example if i checked button in q_c1 then i can see that q_c1 button was selected. in that way i can create a condition in controller :) thank you.

Comment: Then you need to change the filed to something like this; `Html::radio('ModelName['answer']), assuming you have an attribute called answer in your model, but I still don't think it's going to achieve what you want. You now you can still style the radio buttons a bit like you originally did?

Comment: Html::radio('ModelName['answer']) can only assign the name of my radio, but still the value remain 1 can i assign value of every button like q_c1 will have the value of 1 q_c2 = 2 and so on.

i can't style it like the way i wanted ^_^

thank you

Comment: @top In that case, please refer to my original answer!