# yii2 get name instead of id

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

hi i have this weird problem. i had a table relation. and i want to view the related table field name instead of id.

here is my model:

```
public function getQCat()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(QbCategory::className(), ['id' => 'q_cat']);
    }
```

here is my view:

```
<?php echo DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'q_cat',
            'question:ntext',
            'q_c1:ntext',
            'q_c2:ntext',
            'q_c3:ntext',
            'q_c4:ntext',
            'q_ans:ntext',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

that 'q_cat' field in view i want to display name instead of id. i tried using 'q_cat.name' but it says (not set).

thanks.

Comment: Can you please add model query?

Comment: what do you mean model query? i'd included model above :)

Comment: From where you get $model in detail view.

Comment: where did i find that? hepl me i'm new with this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you  QbCategory model is

```
id
name
```

and you want accessing to QbCategory value in your Main  Class 
you could access to the attribute name in this way
in Main class

add relation

```
public function geQcat()
{
    return $this->hasOne(QbCategory::className(),
     ['id' =>   'qcat_id']);  // qcat_id is the column name in Main  class that join QCat to Main
```

then you can build a getter for for QbCategory name

```
public function getQcatname() {  
    return $this->qcat->name; // name is the name of name column in QCat 
}
```

then in your Main Clals  Detail View

```
<?php echo DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'qcatname', // this i the ref for getQcatname function in Main Model
            'question:ntext',
            'q_c1:ntext',
            'q_c2:ntext',
            'q_c3:ntext',
            'q_c4:ntext',
            'q_ans:ntext',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

Comment: thank you for reply. but unfortunately it's an error. by the way i'm using starter kit.

Comment: show the error message  ..  ( and what do you mean with starter kit ???) .. anyway answer  updated with proper class name

Comment: sir i did it correctly. my another question is that. why i need to have a getter for name. when i did a table relation when i'd generated it from gii

Comment: Use getter for simplicity and clarity .. so in the model i have all the concentrated access functions .. this is a programming pattern .. you can use the pattern you prefer .. the important thing is to have consistently the tools needed

Comment: thank you sir. i figured it out. i did not follow the naming convention from my model. instead qCat.name i use q_cat.name. and that's the reason i came here. but base on your answer given. i made it right :).

as always in programming. easiest solution can't be figured out and you always come up to the advance approach. and missed it up until it become an issue. funny thing hehe.

thank you again sir

Answer (score 1):

Easier solution

```
[
    'attribute' => 'q_cat',
    'value => $model->Qcat->qcat_name
]
```